# Call function associated with mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mouseenter

With jQuery, I added a function to an element like this:

```
$('#theId').mouseenter(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Now, I want to call the function associated with `#theId.mouseenter`, from a script. I know this is possible:

```
$('#theId').mouseenter(theFunction);
function theFunction() {
    // ...
}
```

With this, I could call `theFunction()` from a script. But I'd like to know if there is a function to execute the functions associated with `#theId.mouseenter`. It is for example possible to run functions associated with `elem.scroll` by executing `$(elem).scroll();`. Is there something similar for the `mouseenter` event?

Comment: did you at least try `$(elem).mouseenter();` before asking ??

Comment: @adeneo actually, I did, it didn't work (or my code was faulty, which I'm checking now...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger mouseenter :

```
$('#theId').trigger('mouseenter');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`.trigger();`**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#theId').trigger("mouseenter");
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the trigger at all - just `$('#theId').mouseenter();`